# Cannot center align my column

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding and am making a test website, but I have encountered many problems, one of which is centering my columns. One column stays centered as I change the browser size, but the other just keeps to the left. I am not sure what I have done wrong because the code seems to be the same as the code for the right column, please help.

I have tried many different things: margin 0 auto, margin with percentages, padding, and many others but nothing changed.

Only been learning code for about a week and a half... bear with me...

***responsive.css:***

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {

/***************************
HOME
***************************/

#homecol1 {
float: left;
width: 50%;
max-width: 500px;
max-height: 600px;
}

#homecol2 {
float: right;
width: 50%;
margin-bottom: 15.5%;
}
```

***index.html:***

```
<div id="homecol1">
<section class="para">
    <h4 class="homeinfo">Home</h4>
    <p class="homeinfo">my paragraph</p>
</section>
</div>
<div id="homecol2">
    <div id="treelogo">
    <section>
    <center><img class="treehome" src="img/section-logo.png" 
    alt="tree-logo" height="350" width="350"></center>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

***index.css:***

```
#treelogo {
transform: scale(0.3);
margin-right: 40px;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
}

.para {
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
color: #bbb;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 100px;
padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

I wish that I could add more than two images...

[my index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFX0O.png)

[responsive.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz4gd.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text not images.

Comment: you have media queries that check the browser size. you should check that.

Comment: where is the center alignment? I've found the only left/right. You can edit your question and add the `code snippet`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `<center>`. And it is used once. However it's a bad tag for today, you have to use some class for imgs you wanna align at center, then you should specify `display: block; margin:  auto;` because `margin` doesn't work for inline elements that img is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems any of your colums aren't centered at lower resolution, they've got full width. Image is limited by height property and centered by  tag.
To center divs limit them and center with margin e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#homecol1, #homecol2 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me, it centered the items vertically stacked, I am trying to make two columns and center the text within the column.

Comment: to center text in div you should use text-align property https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp